# ValueError: Input has n_features=10 while the model has been trained with n_features=4261

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use trained BoW, tfidf, and SVM model to do prediction:

```
def bagOfWords(files_data):
    count_vector = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()
    return count_vector.fit_transform(files_data)

files = sklearn.datasets.load_files(dir_path)
word_counts = util.bagOfWords(files.data)
tf_transformer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True).fit(word_counts)
X = tf_transformer.transform(word_counts)
clf = sklearn.svm.LinearSVC()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size)
```

I can run following:

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
```

But following will get error:

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
new_word_counts = util.bagOfWords(["a place to listen to music it s making its way to the us"]) 
ready_to_be_predicted = tf_transformer.transform(new_word_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(ready_to_be_predicted)
```

I think am already using the former tf_transform, and don't know why still got the error. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not preserving the CountVectorizer you originally fit the data with.

This bagOfWords call is fitting a separate CountVectorizer in its own scope.

```
new_word_counts = util.bagOfWords(["a place to listen to music it s making its way to the us"])
```

You want to use the one you fit on your training set.

You are also training your transformers with the entire X, including X_test.  You want to exclude your test test from any training, including transformations.

Try something like this.

```
files = sklearn.datasets.load_files(dir_path)

# Split in train/test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(files.data, file.target)

# Fit and tranform with X_train
count_vector = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer()
word_counts = count_vector.fit_transform(X_train)
tf_transformer = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)
X_train = tf_transformer.fit_transform(word_counts)

clf = sklearn.svm.LinearSVC()

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Transform X_test
test_word_counts = count_vector.transform(X_test) 
ready_to_be_predicted = tf_transformer.transform(test_word_counts)
X_test = clf.predict(ready_to_be_predicted)

# Test example
new_word_counts = count_vector.transform["a place to listen to music it smaking its way to the us"]) 

ready_to_be_predicted = tf_transformer.transform(new_word_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(ready_to_be_predicted)
```

Of course, it's much less complicated to combine these transformers into a Pipeline.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html